# Moving Focus to GridView's first item view

Tags: android, android-layout, focus, android-gridview

In my activity i have two fragments 1st one contains a linearlayout and second one contains a gridview and i have to support D-pad navigation in my app.

now when user press key to movetowards grid view i want to show the 1st item of gridview as selected view

[image]

so every time when focus moves from linearlayout to gridview , gridview's first item should get selected/focused

any leads on these is highly appreciated

Comment: always you want to show your first item as selected?

Comment: yes but when focus is moved to grid view

Answer (score -1):

on keypress towards gridview you can call:

```
firstItem.requestFocus();
```

replace "firstItem" by your element name, such as button, edittext, etc

**OR**

you can implement OnFocusChangeListener to your activity and do this:

```
gridView.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
```

and then

```
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

    if(hasFocus){
        firstItem.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

Comment: will implement and let you know !!

Comment: can u tell me how can i get firstItem ?

Comment: firstITem can be your button or edittext or linear layout which is placed inside the 1st item of gridview

Comment: you can also change the color of the layout which you have placed in the 1st item of gridview to show it as focused

Comment: This is not the answer OP asked for. How to focus on particular position of item